# Can you "plug in" to unhandled Promise rejections in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

A while back, v8 gained the [capability to detect Promises that are rejected but have no handlers attached](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3093) ([commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/e68e62c8917405e33155965303bb263fae68fcb0)). This landed in Chrome as a nice console error, especially useful for when you've made a typo or forget to attach a handler:

[image: Example of Chrome reporting a rejected promise with handlers]

I would like to add a handler to take some action (e.g., reporting to an error reporting service) when this happens, similar to the uncaught exception pattern:

```
window.addEventListener("error", handler);
```

Alternatively, I'm looking for any mechanism that I can use to *automatically* invoke some sort of callback when a promise is rejected but not handled on that tick.

Comment: Try ``window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {});`` Good info here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#global-rejection-events

Comment: @Jeff These are plain ol' native Promises as specified by ES2015 and implemented in v8.

Comment: @BinaryMuse: https://github.com/domenic/unhandled-rejections-browser-spec. Those events are going to become standard, and will be supported in Chrome as well.

Comment: If you add a `catch()` at the end of the promises chain, won't you get what you need?

Comment: I wonder if we shouldn't consider dupe-closing in the other direction instead—this one seems better to me, and has more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Until `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', e => ...)` is here you may hack your own Promise constructor which creates original Promise and calls `catch` on it passing:

```
error => {
  var errorEvent = new ErrorEvent('error', {
    message: error.message,
    error: error
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(errorEvent); // For error listeners.
  throw error; // I prefer to see errors on the console.
}
```

But it seems we have to patch `then`, `catch` and `Promise.reject` also -- lots of work.

Someone may want to write a polyfill to emit custom `unhandledrejection` event in such cases.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty since, in the absence of Chrome exposing these v8 internals to us, this is the best option.